# Timeout error on a domain without https

Tags: https, chrome

I have a very old web site running on apache on CentOS. Ever since Chrome made the change to try https first instead of http when user just types "domainname.com", I get timeout errors after a couple of seconds.
Is it possible to somehow remedy this situation without actually adding support for https? Because that would be quite difficult in this case as the version of OS I am running is not supported by letsencrypt.

Comment: Try to specify protocol by hand. i.e. type a complete URL into the address bar: `http://domainname.com/`. Alternatively, try using a proper web browser instead of chrome.

Comment: Another decent solution will be to install a reverse proxy (into another system which supports modern HTTPS), and proxy the requests into the old HTTP server.